# Valet doesn't work. Projects do not run in paths

Tags: php, laravel, macos, valet

I installed the valet, used commands:

`valet link laravel` *in "laravel" project folder*

run `valet restart` and `valet links`

Site **laravel**

SSL -

URL **http://laravel.test**

Path **/Users/me/Sites/laravel**

> At *http://laravel.test* I only see - **It works!**

After `valet secure laravel`

> At *https://laravel.test* I get an error - **ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED**
>
> What am I doing wrong?

*MacOS Mojave, Valet, php@7.3*

Answer (score 0):

Apache was running, solution: **sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl stop**